# Story about a TV salesman who is the Devil; selling TVs with built-in popcorn machines

Tags: story-identification

Would anyone know a science fiction story about a TV salesman who is the Devil; selling TVs with built-in popcorn machines - "Baal TV" - in exchange for people's souls? And who finds that everyone is willing to make that bargain? I think the story is called "Baal TV" but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi there. That's some info aready but could you please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when did you read that? Was it in an anthology, a magazine? Etc, etc

Comment: Hello! Was it a shorter story or a longer story?

Comment: "The Tubes of Baal-Ashteroth" sounds like a right title, but the plot summary I found didn't match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Added Inducement by Robert F. Young](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74308). I read it in the collection [The Worlds of Robert F. Young](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?50561).

> THE ELECTRICAL APPLIANCE STORE was one of many that had sprung up in and around the
> city, seemingly overnight. There were half a dozen TV sets in the window, marked at amazingly low prices, and a window-wide sign boasted; WE'RE PRACTICALLY giving THEM AWAY! 
> "This is the place we've been looking for," Janice said, and she pulled Henry though the entrance and into the store proper. They hadn't gone two steps beyond the entrance when they came to a common standstill. Before them stood a huge and dazzling console with a 24-inch screen, and if you were TV hunting, you couldn't go by it any more than a hungry mouse could go by a new mouse trap baited with his favorite cheese.
> "We can never afford that one," Henry said.
> "But, darling, we can afford to look, can't we?"
> So they looked. They looked at the sleek mahogany cabinet and the cute little double doors that you could dose when you weren't watching your programs; at the screen and the program in progress; at the company's name at the base of the screen - BAAL.

And the TV does indeed make popcorn:

> "What's that for?' Janice asked, pointing at the window.
> Henry leaned forward. "The dial above it says `popcorn but that can't be."
> "Oh, yes it can!" a voice behind them said.

Comment: *huge and dazzling console with a 24-inch screen* - how times change :-)

Comment: @JesseLarner If this is the correct answer, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark under the upvote and downvote buttons ;)

Comment: HEY THAT'S IT! Thank you very much!